# Arduino gsm shield, gsm not init

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, gsm

I am using the example gsm receive SMS example.
This is the part with the issue:

```
  Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM connection
  while (notConnected)
  {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
  Serial.println("Not connected");
  delay(1000);
  }
}

Serial.println("GSM initialized");
Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}
```

this gets printed via serial:

```
Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");
```

but nothing after that.

Could it be due to not enough power?
I am using the mega and the gsm shield and powered from usb.
the only light on the GSM shield is the on led.

When I disconnected and reconnect the usb cable the status led goes on and the net led flashes on and off, then after a few seconds they both go off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If both the LEDs go off then there is an issue with your power supply. Try a USB adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a lot of GSM modules required a lot of power(around 2 Amps) but a lot of USB ports only provide around 0.5 amps. So you have to use a [high amperage USB socket](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rugged-Waterproof-High-Power-USB-4-8-Amp-Charger-Socket-12V-Outlet-Motorcycles-/122652615100) or get a low power gsm module. You can look for the [datasheets](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) for the current consumption of the modules